# How to Response.Write some variable and nothing else should be sent to client except that variable

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

I have a global variable in my javascript, whose value I want to set again from the response I get from server after calling the server through `$.post()`. I use the following code at the server side and write the variable `QS` to the Response Stream after clearing it. So, according to me nothing should be there in the Response except that variables's value.

The code:-

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Write(QS);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

But what is happening is, the variable's value is there in the Response in the beginning but then other things are appended to the Response. I just want the variable's value and nothing else.

When I have Called `CompleteRequest()`, then from where these extra things are getting added to the Response ?

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(QS);
    Response.End();
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: I have read that Response.End() have certain problems with it, that's why I use the above line instead. It sometimes throws exceptions.

Comment: Indeed, it throws the ThreadAbortException.  However, this exception is properly handled by the ASP.NET and nobody will see it.  So, please, try this solution.  Does it work for you?